showing that $\frac{1}{n} S_n \to -1$ almost surely
Original Exercise Text:
Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be independent random variables with
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n = n^2) = \frac{1}{n^2} = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X_n = -1)
$$
for all $n$.
Show for $S_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$ that
$\frac{1}{n} \mathbb{E}[S_n] \to 0$ for all $n$, but
$\frac{1}{n} S_n \to -1$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$.
Question:
I am stuck at the part of showing that
$\frac{1}{n} S_n \to -1$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$
My Approach:
First:
I do not think using the strong law of large numbers and then rewriting the expression asymptotically, i.e. bringing a $-1$ to the RHS, can work since they all have different expectation values depending on $n$.
Second:
since I have to show
$$\mathbb{P}\bigl(\{\omega \in \Omega | \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}S_n(\omega) = -1 \}\bigr)=1$$
Now, I want to better understand the event and analyse the limit expression:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}S_n(\omega) = -1 $$
and I fail to do so confidently.
So I think that in order for this scaled sum to converge against to happen we need that $X_k(\omega)=-1$ for almost all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If this is correct I know how I can proceed on my own (for now).

You've tagged the question with Borel-Cantelli.  This problem practically screams you should use it.

did you read my actual question?

The Borel-Cantelli Lemma says that $\sum_{n}P(X_{n}\neq -1)=\sum_{n}P(X_{n}=n^{2})<\infty$ and hence $P(\{X_{n}\neq -1\,\text{infinitely often}\})=0$.
So, consider the set $\{X_{n}\neq -1\, \text{infinitely often}\}^{c}$ which is a set of probability $1$ and fix an $\omega$ in this set.
As $\omega\in\{X_{n}\neq -1\,\text{infinitely often}\}^{c}$, we must have $X_{n}(\omega)=-1$ for all $n\geq m(\omega)$. i.e. after a certain $m$ (depending on $\omega$), $X_{n}$'s must all be $-1$.
Thus, for all $n>m(\omega)$, you have \begin{align}\frac{S_{n}(\omega)}{n}&=\frac{X_{1}(\omega)+...+X_{m(\omega)-1}(\omega)}{n}+\frac{X_{m(\omega)}(\omega)+...+X_{n}(\omega)}{n}\\\\
&=\frac{X_{1}(\omega)+...+X_{m(\omega)-1}(\omega)}{n}-\frac{n-m+1}{n}\end{align}
Now note that as $m(\omega)$ is finite, $\frac{X_{1}(\omega)+...+X_{m(\omega)-1}(\omega)}{n} 0$ and $\frac{n-m(\omega)+1}{n}\to -1$. This is because, once $\omega$ is fixed, $X_{1}(\omega),...,X_{m(\omega)-1}(\omega)$ are just $m(\omega)-1$ many real numbers.
Thus for $\omega\in \{X_{n}\neq -1\,\text{infinitely often}\}^{c}$, you have $\frac{S_{n}(\omega)}{n}\to -1$.
As $P(\{X_{n}\neq -1\,\text{infinitely often}\}^{c})=-1$ thus you have $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_{n}}{n}\to -1)=1$

Let $w \in \Omega$. If the relation $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n(w)}{n} \not = -1$ is true, then for infinitely many values of $n$, the relation $X_n(w) \not = -1$ is also true. Or in other words, if the relation $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n(w)}{n} \not = -1$ is true, then $w$ is in the set $\{w \in \Omega; X_n(w) \not = -1 {\text{ for infinitely many $n$ }}\}.$ So by definition of almost-sure convergence, it suffices to show that the measure of this set is $0$, or equivalently, that the equation
$\mu(\{w \in \Omega; X_n(w) \not = -1 {\text{ for infinitely many $n$ }}\}) = 0$ is true.
But however, note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\bf{P}}[X_n \not = -1]$ $=$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-2}$ is finite. Using the 1st Borel-Cantelli lemma then , we note that indeed,
$${\bf{P}}[X_n \not = -1 {\text{ for infinitely many $n$ }}] \quad = \quad 0,$$ or equivalently, indeed, $\mu(\{w \in \Omega; X_n(w) \not = -1 {\text{ for infinitely many $n$ }}\}) = 0.$ Thus, as
$$\{w \in \Omega; \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n}{n} \not = -1\} \quad \subseteq \quad \{w \in \Omega; X_n(w) \not = -1 {\text{ for infinitely many $n$ }}\},$$ it follows that
$$\mu(\{w \in \Omega; \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n}{n} \not = -1\}) \quad = \quad 0,$$
and so  a.s. convergence follows.

this is what I wanted to do after my actual question would have been answered. But in your first sentence you actually answered it. So anyways it is useful.
